# How to read data from USART using interrupt int0?

Tags: assembly, avr, avrdude

I need to read data from usart using interrupt int0, but I don't understand how to do this. It's a task from my teacher in a university. I can read data from usart using interrupt usart.  I tried to allow read from usart using a button, but I think this is weird. Usart can read only one byte. Can I read several bytes from usart? Maybe is there some settings in a virtual terminal?

My project in proteus.

[image]

```
.equ bitrate=9600
.equ baud =1000000/(16*bitrate)-1
;====================================================================
; RESET and INTERRUPT VECTORS
;====================================================================

      ; Reset Vector
      .org 0
      rjmp  Start
      .org 0x001
      rjmp int0_interrupt
      ;.org 0x002
      ;rjmp int1_interrupt
      .org 0x00b
      rjmp usart_rxc

;====================================================================
; CODE SEGMENT
;====================================================================

Start:
      ldi r16, low(ramend)
      out spl,r16
      ldi r16,high(ramend)
      out sph,r16

        ldi r16, high(baud)
        out ubrrh,r16
        ldi r16, low(baud)
        out ubrrl, r16

        ldi r16,0xff   
        out ddra,r16

        ldi r16,0b00000010 ;
        out portd,r16 

        ldi r16,$0a; 
        out mcucr,r16
        ldi r16,$c0; 
        out gimsk,r16

        clr r16;
        out gifr,r16

        ldi r16, 0b10010000;
        out ucsrb,r16
        ldi r16,0b10000110
        out ucsrc,r16


        ldi r16,$70
        mov xl,r16
        clr xh



        clr r18
sei;

m1:
cpi r18,3 
brne m1
rjmp k

int0_interrupt:
        cpi r17,0x00
        breq c1
        cpi r17,0xff
        breq c2


        c1:
        ldi r17, 0xff
        out porta,r17
        rjmp exit

        c2:
        ldi r17,0x00
        out porta,r17
        rjmp exit

    exit:
reti

usart_rxc:

    cpi r17, 0xff
    brne exit2

    in r20,udr
    st x+,r20

    exit2:
reti

k:
Loop:
      rjmp  Loop
```

Comment: It has no sense. You can read bytes from USART only when they are transmitted.Obviously you cannot read a byte on arbitrary event if the byte is not being transmitted by the remote side. Although, the AVR USART has a one-byte input buffer, so you can extract a byte from the buffer (simple reading the UDR register) after it was received by the USART. Please, clarify what do you mean by "read data from usart using interrupt int0"

Comment: @AterLux "Enter the source data for the INT0 interrupt routine through the USART channel". I have a program for checking the input array. This program should get data from usart.